# Powershell : ExtractToDirectory with no folder created

Tags: powershell, directory, unzip

I've got a zip file with this structure:  `test.zip -> Mark -> Today-> *.* ( every files)`

When I extract it , as a result I get this : `test (folder) -> Mark (folder) -> Today ->*.* ( every files)`

How Can I get this structure :  `Today (folder) ->*.* (every files)`

I mean , I trying to avoid the first two folders creation.

The best thing to be would be extract only the files without folders

```
 function Unzip
 {
     param([string]$zipfile, [string]$out)
     [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory($zipfile, $out)
 }
```

`unzip Test.zip $testPath`

Edit :
I'm sorry I made a mistake about the question.
The right question is  : How Can I extract only the files or the last folders (today). I wondering if I need a temporary folder or if there is a option for that, but reading the doc it seems not

Comment: You forgot to post the code you'r eusing to expand your archive.

Comment: Yeah, there must be something in your code because the `[System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::ExtractToDirectory` method extract in the directory you specify, meaning if you specify the Mark folder, it will extract files there and not in an arbitrary test folder. This method does keep the file structure intact though so if you want to get rid of Mark too, then something else in ZipArchive class might be useful, but not ExtractToDirectory (Reference to ZipArchive: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.ziparchive?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: I need some time to investigate . Don't close the post please . thank

Comment: Is there a special reason why your'e not using the standard Powershell cmdlet [Expand-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-5.1)?  ... no need to re-invent the wheel.  ;-)

Comment: I didn't know that :) I tried .It has a beatiful text graphic but I don't know how I can only extract the last folder or the only files.There is no option , may be I have to search for method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you'd proceed to extract only the files without consideration for the folder structure.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.IO.Compression.FileSystem'

function Unzip {
    param([string]$zipfile, [string]$out)


    $Archive = [System.IO.Compression.ZipFile]::OpenRead($zipfile)
    Foreach ($entry in $Archive.Entries.Where( { $_.Name.length -gt 0 })) {
        [System.IO.Compression.ZipFileExtensions]::ExtractToFile($entry, "$out\$($entry.Name)")
    }
    $Archive.Dispose()
}

# Example 
Unzip -zipfile 'Z:\_tmp\impfiles\1.zip' -out 'Z:\_tmp\impfiles'
```

Of course, now that you discarded the folder structure, you will have to implement — if needed — some way to deal with the possibility of file name clash (For instance, if you have a Readme.txt in 2 different folders)